# Difference between catmull-clark and (nurbs or B-spline patches)

Tags: computational-geometry, spline, nurbs

Catmull-Clark works for arbitrary polygon meshes, which seems it is the superset of NURBS or equal to B-spline patches.
However, the method converges to bicubic B-spline surfaces based on [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface). What is the relationship between those?